# Selector to get prev of parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to achieve the following only using selector

```
$(this:parent:prev)
```

I wish to get prev of parent. I want to only use selector

Comment: Why do you want to only use a selector rather than chaining the `.parent` and `.prev` calls?

Comment: There are no selectors that can do this. Selectors are for *filtering*, not for tree traversal.

Comment: @A.Wolff No, you can't. (In other words, I would be very interested to see this.)

Comment: @Tomalak Of course you cannot, my bad!

Comment: @A.Wolff For creating custom selector check http://stackoverflow.com/a/33908446/2025923

Comment: @Tushar Ya you can create custom selector but this is filtering element itself, returning boolean regarding passed selector. You cannot return other element.

Answer (score 4):

There is no parent selector and previous sibling selector, so you've to use `parent` and `prev` methods

```
$(this).parent().prev();
```

And if you look at the [jQuery Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/parent-selector/) for `:parent`, you don't really want `:parent`.

> Select all elements that have at least one child node (either an element or text).

---

You can create a custom `:parent` selector in jQuery as follow:

```js
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  parent: function(element, _, m) {
    return $(element).parent();
  }
});

$('span:parent').css('color', 'green').prepend('Hello World!');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <span>Bye!</span>
</div>
```

Comment: [Extending jQuery’s selector capabilities](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/)

Comment: Using your custom pseudo selector, you are targeting element itself, not the parent. BTW, expression `return $(element).parent();` will always be truly

Answer (score 3):

In pure JavaScript this would be:

```
this.parentNode.prevElementSibling
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$(this).parent('div').prev();
```