# Creating dropdown menu from simple list

Tags: jquery, list

I have current list look like:

```
<ul>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">_Submenu a</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">_Submenu b</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">_Submenu c</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">_Submenu x</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">_Submenu y</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

How can I use Jquery to create Drop-down menu like that.

```
  <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
         <ul>
           <li><a href="#">_Submenu a</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">_Submenu b</a></li>
           <li><a href="#">_Submenu c</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">_Submenu x</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">_Submenu y</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
 </ul>
```

It means some items after main item which have "_" will be added as dropdown items for main item. Thank for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve the effect you're looking for by using the following logic.

1. Create a common cache variable to hold the previous top-level menu.
2. Loop through all menu list items checking to see whether the text begins with an underscore.

   - If it does, append this to the previous top-level menu.
   - If it does not, append a new unordered list element to this list item and cache the new list in the previous top-level menu variable.
3. Once the loop has finished you can select all lists that are empty and remove them (`.find('ul:empty').remove()`).

In the example below I have favoured Native DOM API methods instead of their jQuery counterparts in a few instances because:

1. `$(this).append('<ul></ul>')` returns `$(this)` instead of the newly created list. The work around is to add another line of code, or just use the DOM API `this.appendChild($('<ul>')[0])` which does return the newly created list. And...
2. It just seems wasteful to use jQuery in situations where it is just as simple to use the DOM API. <sup>see: [youmightnotneedjquery.com](http://youmightnotneedjquery.com)</sup>

```js
var prev;
$('.menu li').each(function(){
    if(/^_/.test(this.textContent) && prev) {
        prev.appendChild(this);
    } else {
        prev = this.appendChild($('<ul>')[0]);
    }
}).find('ul:empty').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu">
   <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">_Submenu a</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">_Submenu b</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">_Submenu c</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">_Submenu x</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">_Submenu y</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

The example above results in the following HTML structure:

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">_Submenu a</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">_Submenu b</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">_Submenu c</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">_Submenu x</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">_Submenu y</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Tiny. Thank you very much. Great result.

Answer (score 5):

```js
// Create custom selectors
$.extend($.expr[':'], {
  startsWith: function(e, i, m) {  
    return $(e).text().trim().indexOf(m[3]) === 0;
  }
});

$("li:not(:startsWith(_))").each(function(){  // LI that are not _Sub
  if($(this).next("li:startsWith(_)").length) // If my next() is _Sub, start grouping:
  $("<ul/>", {
    html: $(this).nextUntil("li:not(:startsWith(_))"),
    appendTo: this
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">_Submenu a</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">_Submenu b</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">_Submenu c</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">_Submenu x</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">_Submenu y</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a></li>
</ul>
```

**Here's the HTML result:**

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">_Submenu a</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">_Submenu b</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">_Submenu c</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 3</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">_Submenu x</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">_Submenu y</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Menu 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi Roko. It seems not look like result I want.

Comment: @MinhAnh **Fixed** added another selector

Comment: I have not known that we can create custom jQuery selectors until reading your answer. It's really elegant.

Comment: @HieuLe Yes, and pretty useful sometimes!

Comment: @HieuLe I've simplified my answer - I removed the custom selector `:notStartsWith()` in favor of the already existent `:not()` :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Didn't know about creating custom selectors, can you please share the jQuery Doc links for this

Comment: @Tushar jQuery uses the Sizzle engine https://sizzlejs.com/ for selectors that are not in the scope of CSS2.1/3 selectors using `.find()`. https://github.com/jquery/sizzle/wiki#extension-api. Here's an interesting reading: http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/extending-jquerys-selector-capabilities/

Answer (score 2):

```js
$('.group1').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
$('.group2').wrapAll('<ul></ul>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a>
  </li>
  <li class='group1'><a href="#">_Submenu a</a>
  </li>
  <li class='group1'><a href="#">_Submenu b</a>
  </li>
  <li class='group1'><a href="#">_Submenu c</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a>
  </li>
  <li class='group2'><a href="#">_Submenu x</a>
  </li>
  <li class='group2'><a href="#">_Submenu y</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">Menu 4</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Try this way

Use [.wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around each element in the set of matched elements.

Use [.wrapAll()](http://api.jquery.com/wrapall/)

> Description: Wrap an HTML structure around all elements in the set of matched elements.

Comment: Thank but wrapping will wrap all and cannot add them into corresponding items. I am not down vote. Can you please explain?

Comment: isnt it what you wanted?if not what you want?@MinhAnh

Comment: you can add `$('a:contains(_Submenu)').parent().wrap('<ul></ul>')` like this to make the parent of a to be wrapped in `<ul>` @MinhAnh

Comment: @MinhAnh you can give class to the `li` you want to group to make it easier to select them and you can use the class to form the ul for those li

Comment: Hi Guradio. The result like Roko and they are still not wrapped into <li></li> corresponding item like result I want. Any idea?

Comment: @MinhAnh you can add class and use that class and use wrapAll