# How to addClass li wrapping ul

Tags: jquery, list, drop-down-menu, dropdown

I get the code at [Creating dropdown menu from simple list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33908275/2621248)

```
  <ul id="menu">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">_Submenu x</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">_Submenu y</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

I tried to add the class li wrapper ul, which has been added

```
var prev;
$('#nav li').each(function(){
    if(/^_/.test (this.textContent) && prev){
        prev.appendChild(this);
        $("#nav ul li ul").prev().addClass("sub-icon");
        $("#nav ul li ul li a").each(function(){
        $(this).text($(this).text().replace (/[_]/,""))
        })
    }else{
        prev = this.appendChild($('<ul class ="sub-nav">')[0]);
    }
}).find('ul:empty').remove();
```

and generate the html structure as follows:

```
  <ul id="nav">
      <li><a class="sub-icon" href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="sub-icon" href="#">Menu 2</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a class="sub-icon" href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

How can I produce a structure like this, just one that is added class sub-icon

```
 <ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a class="sub-icon" href="#">Menu 2</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu x</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Submenu y</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you wish to add a class to the `li` which contains a `ul`...

Try:

```
$("#nav ul li ul").parent("li").addClass("sub-icon");
```

Comment: this will add a class sub-icon to all li lists, so it did not work, there are other solutions?

Comment: To all `li` that has a `ul` as a child... Yes. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Sorry, I had misplaced it, I try again succeeded, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this in different way by filtering the subs and modifying their text first. Then loop over the subs and append to sub `<ul>` if it already exists or add it if it doesn't

```js
// filter out the sub menu items and remove the `_`
var $subs = $('#nav li').filter(function(){
  var $link = $(this).find('a'),
  txt = $link.text(),
  isSub = txt[0]==='_';
  if(isSub){
    $link.text(txt.slice(1))
  }
  return isSub;  
});
// loop over sub menu items
$subs.each(function(){
  var $prev = $(this).prev(),
    $prevUl = $prev.find('ul');
  if(!$prevUl.length){
    // if prev `<li>` doesn't have sub `<ul>` add it and add the link class
    $prevUl = $('<ul>').appendTo($prev);
    $prev.find('a').addClass('sub-icon')
  }
  $prevUl.append(this);
  
})
```

```css
a.sub-icon{color:red}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="nav">
      <li><a href="#">Menu 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">_Submenu x</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">_Submenu y</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Menu 3</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: wow, perfect, good job, I am confused which want to use the code, but I would try the code from you, thanks for your help